# Bullets in moderncv are not in the centre

Tags: itemize, moderncv

Hi i recently observed that when you use itemize with bullets, the bullets do not come to the centre of the letter/word itemized but they are aligned lower. On the other hand, if you itemize with dashes then it comes to the centre. I compile my .tex file with Xelatex.

Any solutions for that?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry} 

\moderncvicons{awesome}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\email{a@a.net}

\nopagenumbers{}                                                                                % comment to show page numbers

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\cventry{2012--Present}{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst}{\textsc{Lehman Brothers}}{Los Angeles}{}{}

\begin{itemize}
\item Learned how to make amazing coffee
\item Finally determined the reason for \textsc{PC LOAD LETTER}:
\end{itemize}   

\end{document}
```

Commenting or uncommenting the modercvicons{awesome} will give you the idea

Comment: in both cases the symbol isn't explicitly centred (and what does that mean, centre on uppercase?, lowercase?, centre between the baselines? ) It just prints the symbol from the font so it is the choice of the font designer.  Your question would be _much_ easier to answer if you provided a full small document with an itemized list, and described exactly how you with the output to change. Then people can check their answers on the supplied test document.

Comment: Ok I observed that this problem comes when I use the \moderncvicons{awesome} instead of the classic marvosym ones. Although you can find the same problem in the moderncv samples, fancy one uses awesome icons while classic uses the marvosym and you can see the difference

Comment: But it is still better to make such an example and add it to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\show` to see what `\labelitemi` is and then adjust it to raise the bullet, normally in the preamble but here mid-document to show before and after

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry} 

\moderncvicons{awesome}

%\show\labelitemi% ->\strut \textcolor {color1}{\tiny \faCircleO }

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\email{a@a.net}

\nopagenumbers{}                                                                                % comment to show page numbers

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\cventry{2012--Present}{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst}{\textsc{Lehman Brothers}}{Los Angeles}{}{}

\begin{itemize}
\item Learned how to make amazing coffee
\item Finally determined the reason for \textsc{PC LOAD LETTER}:
\end{itemize}   

\bigskip

\renewcommand\labelitemi{%
  \strut
  \raisebox{1.5pt}{\textcolor {color1}{\tiny \faCircleO }}}


\begin{itemize}
\item Learned how to make amazing coffee
\item Finally determined the reason for \textsc{PC LOAD LETTER}:
\end{itemize}   

\end{document}
```